# Twitter Apps For Multiple Accounts

Tags: api, twitter

I'm a web developer and I'm currently working on several clients websites ( + several blogs of my own ) and I'd like to use the API to create a auto tweet script for ech, however I don't particularly want to set up as a developper on each account that I create - How can I create an App using my own profile but use it for a sepperate clients account? Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

`<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/{screen_name}" data-widget-id="{widget_id}" data-screen-name="{screen_name}">Tweets by @{screen_name}</a>`

Pass the account name in place of screen_name then you get the feed of that account